# Jsp Page Show İ, Ü AS Ä On Server

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, utf-8

This is the first time I encounter this problem. I have a jsp page and it is using bootstrap. In local work with netbeans - apache tomcat there is no character problem but when I upload to server Turkish characters like İ, Ü shown as  Ä

I am always using this code for UTF-8 problems :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
%>
```

But now, it does not work. Did anyone see an error like this?

How can I fix that?

Comment: You can check if the browser doesn't use another encoding for this URL. Browsers can be told to ignore the given encoding for specific URLs! Also, if you save the webpage to disk and look at it in a hex editor, do the expected hex values come out (i.e. C4 B0  for İ)?

Comment: @MrLister is that a browser can show different encoding, same pages with different url ?

Comment: I mean if you tell the browser to use a certain encoding for a certain webpage (for example with Firefox it's View -> Text Encoding) then Firefox will remember that setting for that page and use it next time you visit. That's why these things are the first you should check. Edit: in your case, something else seemed to be the case, but checking the browser won't do any harm.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it like this but it seems it is not healthy solution :

Get Parameter

```
    String rsubject = ""+request.getParameter("subject");
```

Then transform to UTF-8 as new string.

```
    byte[] brsubject = new byte[rsubject.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < rsubject.length(); i++) brsubject[i] = (byte) rsubject.charAt(i);
    String subject = new String(brsubject, "UTF-8");
```

It is working but if there is any healty solution, you have to share.